# Adding a subcolumn to pandas dataframe csv output

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a couple of questions as a noob on Python.
I am working on putting a output of my data to a csv and I have a certain condition on the way the data is sorted by in the output:

I want the output to look something like this:

```
Format: Area,soltal,latitud,dag,solighetsfaktor,f(t,latitud),W(t) 
Januari:
450 7 56 1 0.5 0.1215 23.25
450 7 56 2 0.2 0.1224 9.44
450 7 56 3 0.9 0.1234 43.17
...
February:
450 7 56 1 0.5 0.1215 23.25
450 7 56 2 0.2 0.1224 9.44
450 7 56 3 0.9 0.1234 43.17
```

So I thought about using pandas to convert to a csv file and it works out fine except I am missing the "Januari:" bit.
The idea is that I have 360 days and that every 30 day is a month of the year and so every day (column: dag) is sorted by the "subcolumn".

Am I on the right track?

This is my code

```
def tabelloutput():
    #df = pd.DataFrame()
    area = list()
    soltal = list()
    lat = list()
    time = list()
    solighetsfaktor = list()
    modell = list()
    for i in range(1,91):
        latitud = Latitud(i)
        for z in range(0,360):
            area += [Area[0]]
            soltal += [Soltal[0]]
            lat += [latitud.latitud]
            time += [latitud.tid()[z]]
            solighetsfaktor += [latitud.solighetsfaktor()[z]]
            modell += [latitud.modell(latitud.extrapolering(latitud.energifunktion(latitud.tid(),latitud.latitud)), latitud.solighetsfaktor(), Area, Soltal)[z]]
    df= pd.DataFrame({'area': area, 'soltal': soltal, 'latitud': lat, 'tid': time, 'solighetsfaktor': solighetsfaktor, 'modell': modell})
    arrays = [np.array(['Januari', 'Februari'])]
    export_csv = df.to_csv (r'export_dataframe4 .csv', index = time, header=True)

tabelloutput()
```

Comment: So you want for each month a csv sheet? Or just another column with 1-12 for January...December?

Comment: Hey, I just realized I was not as clear as I should have been!
I just want another column for the months, check out the updated format now